# How can I increment a loop inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in modal.data.answers">
   <div ng:show="selected == ????">
      {{ answer.text }}
   </div>
</div>
```

My ng-repeat will if I am correct give me four inner divs if there are four answers. How can I make it also set the value of selected to equal 3, 4, 5 and 6 for each of the divs respectively ?  Also if another answer is added then can I make it so the next will have a value of "selected == 7"

Comment: Consider that $index is a "view thing" and that when using filtering and/or ordering in your list the results might be unexpected. For example $index = 0 will not always correspond to the first answer in your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div with ng-show should be:

```
<div ng:show="selected == ($index+3)">
```

Comment: When I check the dom this gives: <div ng-repeat="answer in modal.data.answers" ng:show="selected == ($index+3)" class="ng-scope" style="display: none;">

Comment: Do any of the parent divs have a ng-controller tag? If you can demonstrate your problem on a fiddle it will help me understand it better.

Comment: I'm opening this up now as another more specific question with a plunker. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in modal.data.answers">
  <div ng:show="selected == $index">
    {{ answer.text }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but what I need is to have "selected == 3" then "selected == 4"

Answer (score 0):

`{{$index + 3}}` seems to be what is needed.

Comment: I'm going to try and create a Plunkr for this. The above gives me what I want to see in the dom but there are more problems. Will update soon.